# How to update UITabBarController from a Helper class?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a help class like this:

```
class NotificationHelper {

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        //super.init()

        managedObjectContext = context
    }

    //functions related to Core Data

    //update Badge
    func updateBadge() {
            var count = 1
            let currentCount = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue

            if currentCount != nil {
                count = Int(currentCount!)! + 1
            }

            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue = String(count)
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure how to get a reference to tabBarController so I can update it. I tried making the class inherit from UIViewController, but I think I was going down the wrong path there.

Also, am I correct in passing managedObjectContext like this? So that this class will be able to access Core Data.

Comment: Is the TabBarController, rootViewController or a child of rootViewController. Then using UIApplication you can access it. Passing Context is fine.

Comment: Ok, good to know. I just decided to pass the tabBarController as a parameter when called, instead of making the class inherit from somewhere. I'll add that as an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

Instead of trying to inherit from somewhere, I decided to pass the UITabBarController as a parameter when needed:

```
func updateTabBarBadge(tabBarController: UITabBarController) {
```

It just means I have to call updateTabBarBadge every time I want to update it, instead of having other functions update it for me.